# Subtract values in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to subtract two values from two hashes. To know the growth delta that I have.

My hash look like this:

```
[
 {:device=>"router", :portmax=>"Port 1/5/3:2006.0", :discardmax=>16617331511, :timeCapturedmax=>"February 18, 2018 at 09:27 AM", :time_unixmax=>1518964024}, 
 {:device=>"router", :portmax=>"Port 1/5/3:2006.0", :discardmax=>16617216094, :timeCapturedmax=>"February 18, 2018 at 09:22 AM", :time_unixmax=>1518963724}, 
 {:device=>"router", :portmax=>"Port 1/5/3:2006.0", :discardmax=>16617202279, :timeCapturedmax=>"February 18, 2018 at 09:18 AM", :time_unixmax=>1518963485}, 
 {:device=>"router", :portmax=>"Port 1/5/3:2006.0", :discardmax=>16616985649, :timeCapturedmax=>"February 18, 2018 at 09:12 AM", :time_unixmax=>1518963135}, 
 {:device=>"router", :portmax=>"Port 1/5/3:2006.0", :discardmax=>16616404836, :timeCapturedmax=>"February 18, 2018 at 09:07 AM", :time_unixmax=>1518962829},  
 {:device=>"router", :portmax=>"Port 1/5/3:2006.0", :discardmax=>16616368250, :timeCapturedmax=>"February 18, 2018 at 09:03 AM", :time_unixmax=>1518962583}
]
```

I want the following as a result:

```
Rate_Discard = [{:device=>"router", :discard_sub=>115417}, {:device=>"router", :discard_sub=>13815}, {:device=>"router", :discard_sub=>216630}]
```

Comment: If your array is `arr`, `arr[0][:discardmax]-arr[1][:discardmax] #=> 115417`, `arr[1][:discardmax]-arr[2][:discardmax]  #=> 13815` and `arr[2][:discardmax]-arr[3][:discardmax] #=> 216630`. What about the other three consecutive pairs (2->3, 3->4 and 4->5)?  You have an array of hashes, not a hash.

Comment: When you give an example it's helpful to assign a variable to each input object. Here you have just one input object, an array of hashes, so you might assign the variable `arr` to it, as I've done in my answer. That way, readers can refer to those variables (here just `arr`) in answers and comments without having to define them.

Comment: “I want the following as a result”—when a developer want something as a result, the proper action would be to go code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr = [
  {:device=>"router", :portmax=>"Port 1/5/3:2006.0", :discardmax=>16617331511, 
     :timeCapturedmax=>"February 18, 2018 at 09:27 AM", :time_unixmax=>1518964024},
  {:device=>"router", :portmax=>"Port 1/5/3:2006.0", :discardmax=>16617216094,
     :timeCapturedmax=>"February 18, 2018 at 09:22 AM", :time_unixmax=>1518963724},
  {:device=>"router", :portmax=>"Port 1/5/3:2006.0", :discardmax=>16617202279,
     :timeCapturedmax=>"February 18, 2018 at 09:18 AM", :time_unixmax=>1518963485},
  {:device=>"router", :portmax=>"Port 1/5/3:2006.0", :discardmax=>16616985649,
     :timeCapturedmax=>"February 18, 2018 at 09:12 AM", :time_unixmax=>1518963135},
  {:device=>"router", :portmax=>"Port 1/5/3:2006.0", :discardmax=>16616404836,
     :timeCapturedmax=>"February 18, 2018 at 09:07 AM", :time_unixmax=>1518962829},
  {:device=>"router", :portmax=>"Port 1/5/3:2006.0", :discardmax=>16616368250,
     :timeCapturedmax=>"February 18, 2018 at 09:03 AM", :time_unixmax=>1518962583}
]

arr.each_cons(2).map do |g,h|
  { device: g[:device], discard_sub: g[:discardmax]-h[:discardmax] }
end
  #=> [{:device=>"router", :discard_sub=>115417},
  #    {:device=>"router", :discard_sub=>13815},
  #    {:device=>"router", :discard_sub=>216630},
  #    {:device=>"router", :discard_sub=>580813},
  #    {:device=>"router", :discard_sub=>36586}]
```

Comment: Hello, if I am have this array: